# Docker: Create multiple containers of the same image, with Auto-Incrementing

Tags: docker

I am unsure if this is even a good practice, but I am wanting to specify a number of docker images to launch. Ideally it would auto-increment the port and tmp data location.

Here is my current command:

`sudo docker run -it -d --restart=always -p=0.0.0.0:9220:9222 -m 1G -v /tmp/chromedata/:/data alpeware/chrome-headless-trunk`

Ideally I'd want to be able to spawn, say 5 of these - auto incrementing such as this:

```
Name     Data              Port

Chrome1 /tmp/chrome1data/ 9220:9222

Chrome2 /tmp/chrome2data/ 9221:9222

Chrome3 /tmp/chrome3data/ 9222:9222

Chrome4 /tmp/chrome4data/ 9223:9222

Chrome5 /tmp/chrome5data/ 9224:9222
```

I am open to any other ideas, basically the endgoal is to rapidly create and easily manage containers of the same image.

WARNING: Docker noob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to create a little bash script do increment the port number, e.g.

```
for x in $(seq 0 4); do
  # increment the port number
  port=$((9220 + $x))
  sudo docker run -it -d --restart=always \
  -p=0.0.0.0:$port:9222 \ 
  -m 1G \
  -v /tmp/chromedata/:/data \
  --name container-$x \
  alpeware/chrome-headless-trunk
done
```

You also assign name for the container (--name parameter_ for easier identification.

Comment: I forgot how powerful bash can be, I'll try this out now.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you may want to extend the complexity of this automation in the future, I'd highly recommend checking out the [Docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), which would let you write arbitrarily complex container deployment logic without having to fight with Bash syntax.